# Getting all the dynamically rendered form elements on submit - react

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, react-router

I have a modal with a form with which the form fields are rendered dynamically. I need to collect all the fields with value entered by the user and send it to back end. Here is my component code to render the dynamic form fields:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Button, Form, Input } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const FormItem = Form.Input;
var urlPrefix = "http://localhost:8000/"
class CreateForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    columns : [],
    formLayout: 'vertical',
  }

  handleOk = (e) => {

    //PLEASE HELP ME HERE

    e.preventDefault();
    this.collection.add(this.state);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch(urlPrefix + 'api/modules/3', {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('token'),
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    }).then(response => response.json().then(data => ({
      data: data, status: response.status}),))
      .then(a => {
      var field, fields = []
      a.data.module_fields.forEach((element) =>{
        field = {
          placeholder: element.text,
          label: element.name,
          key: element.id,
          default_value : element.default_value,
          required : element.required
        }
        fields.push(field)
      });
      const children = [];
      fields.forEach(function(element){
        children.push(
            <FormItem
              label={element.label}
              key={element.key}
              id={element.label}
              placeholder={element.placeholder}
            />
        );
      })
      this.setState({fields: children})
    })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Form
          className="ant-advanced-search-form"
        >
          {this.state.fields}
          <Button key="back" onClick={this.handleCancel}>Close</Button>,
          <Button key="submit" type="primary" loading={loading} onClick={this.handleOk}>
            Create
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default CreateForm
```

I have fields with different datatypes and it comes in the API response and need to make the input accordingly.

Please help me with the handleOk function on how to collect the form fields with variables entered by the user as the current one is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of handling `Button`'s `onClick` event,

```
<Button key="submit" type="primary" loading={loading} onClick={this.handleOk}>
    Create
</Button>
```

use `Form`'s `onSubmit` event to capture the values, also move `loading` to the form

```
<Form
      className="ant-advanced-search-form"
      loading="{loading}"
      onSubmit="{this.handleOk}"
>
```

and change the `Button`'s type to `submit`

```
<Button key="submit" type="submit">Create</Button>
```

See [Form | Semantic UI docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/collections/form#form-example-capture-values) for details.